# Calculate employee wage

Tags: c++, beginner, homework, finance

This is for a class assignment. The objective is to write a program that will take in user input for employee information and print the wage based on hours worked.

Please review my code.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GetSalary(int,int,int,int);
int GetYearsOfService(int);


int main()
{
    int employeeId, hoursWorked, yearJoined, fullTime;

    cout << "Employee ID: ";
    cin >> employeeId;

    cout << "Hours Worked: ";
    cin >> hoursWorked;

    cout << "Year Joined: ";
    cin >> yearJoined;

    cout << "FullTime Status (0 for no, 1 for yes): ";
    cin >> fullTime;

    double salary = GetSalary(employeeId, hoursWorked, yearJoined, fullTime);
    double taxes = salary * 0.15;

    cout << endl << "Empolyee ID: " << employeeId << endl << "\tFull time?: ";

    if (fullTime == 0)
        cout << "No";
    else
        cout << "Yes";

    cout << endl << "\tHours worked: " << hoursWorked << endl << "\tWages (after tax) for the month: $"
         << salary - taxes << endl << "\tAmount withheld for tax: $" << taxes;

    return 0;
}

int GetSalary(int employeeId, int hoursWorked, int yearJoined, int fullTime) {
    double hourlyWage = 14;

    //Get the hourly wage
    int wage = 14;

    if( wage>=50 && wage < 100){
        wage += 1.25;
    }else if( wage < 160){
        wage += 2.0;
    }else{
        wage += 3.0;
    }

    double baseSalary = hourlyWage * hoursWorked;
    int yearsOfService = GetYearsOfService(yearJoined);

    //Check if any additional benefits/bonusses are to be paid
    if (fullTime == 1)
    {
        baseSalary += (35 *yearsOfService);
        baseSalary += 300;
    }
    else {
        if (yearsOfService > 5)
            baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService);
    }
    return baseSalary;
}

int GetYearsOfService(int yearJoined) {
    time_t curTime = time(NULL);

    int elapsed = curTime / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

    return 1970 + elapsed - yearJoined;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first review in awhile, this is short, sorry. I'm sure others will add more.

1. Please stop doing `using namespace std`. Read
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
2. Using `double` for representing currency is
   [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).
   But since this is an assignment, it probably won't matter much.
3. Use constant variables to represent magic numbers like `.15` and
   `3.0`. Create a `const` variable named `TAX_RATE` for instance.
4. You are returning an `int` yet `salary` is of type `double`?
5. `time_t curTime = time(NULL);`

   Use
   [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)
   (C++11).

Comment: 1 isn't a major issue in this case since it's being used just before `main` is declared, but I agree that it should be moved inside `main` instead.

Answer (score 3):

- You can define `main()` lastly, eliminating the need for function prototypes.
- Try to keep variables as close in scope as possible.  You're "listing" declarations at the top of `main()` instead of declaring/initializing them where they're first used.

  In this case, declare each of these variables in front of the respective `cin`s.
- You don't need all of these `std::endl`s, which perform flushes:

  > ```
  > cout << endl << "Empolyee ID: " << employeeId << endl << "\tFull time?: ";
  > ```

  Instead, use `"\n"` to output a newline without a flush:

  ```
  cout << "\nEmpolyee ID: " << employeeId << "\n\tFull time?: ";
  ```

  (Also, "Empolyee" is misspelled)
- It's unnecessary to have an explicit `return 0` at the end of `main()`. As successful termination is already implied at that point, the compiler should do this return automatically.
- This simple conditional:

  > ```
  > if (fullTime == 0)
  >     cout << "No";
  > else
  >     cout << "Yes";
  > ```

  can be shortened to a single-line [ternary (`?:`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B) statement:

  ```
  std::cout << (fullTime == 0) ? "No" : "Yes";
  ```

  Here, the first part after the `?` is for true, and the second part is for false.
- Measurements of time shouldn't be with an `int` (a signed type), which can hold negative values.  The types for `elapsed` and the function's return should at least be `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers (which both make excellent points):

Firstly, try not to mince [indent/brace styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), pick one and stick to it. (Doesn't matter too much in an assignment, but your tutor may give you praise for it)

The two lines

```
baseSalary += (35 *yearsOfService);
baseSalary += 300;
```

can be folded into the singular

```
baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService) + 300;
```

(also note the spaces around the `*`, this prevents confusion with pointer dereferencing, though I expect you haven't been taught about those yet)

This if statement:

```
if (fullTime == 1)
{
    baseSalary += (35 *yearsOfService);
    baseSalary += 300;
}
else {
    if (yearsOfService > 5)
        baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService);
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
if (fullTime == 1)
{
    baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService) + 300;  
}
else if (yearsOfService > 5)
{
    baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService);
}
```

or if you prefer to omit the braces:

```
if (fullTime == 1)
    baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService) + 300;  
else if (yearsOfService > 5)
    baseSalary += (35 * yearsOfService);
```

Also, I could be wrong, but `fullTime` looks like it should be a `true`/`false` value, i.e. a [`bool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a.aspx)

I can't say anything much about the validity of the code since I don't know how the wages are calculated, but I'll assume the calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This whole block

```
 //Get the hourly wage
int wage = 14;

if( wage>=50 && wage < 100){
    wage += 1.25;
}else if( wage < 160){
    wage += 2.0;
}else{
    wage += 3.0;
}
```

is unused, since you don't use `wage` anywhere else... in addition since `wage` is 14 you already know the results of all the `ifs`, so they are doubly useless.